# Building and displaying an html file in OS X

Tags: html, swift, macos, wkwebview

I am building an OS X app using Swift and one of the things I would like to do is to build an HTML string in code and then display that page in a web view.

I can load an `NSURLRequest` into that webView, but I do not know how to display a "virtual" page so to speak.

If I load a preset page into my Xcode Project called `main.html`, then I load it like this.

```
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("main", withExtension: "html")
let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!)
self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(myRequest)
```

However, my html page body is currently within a string variable named `body`.

Is there an easy way to do this with Swift?
Do I need to create a temporary file on disk first, load it then delete it afterwards?

Can someone please suggest the best method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WKWebView method [loadHTMLString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:) to use a string as the contents of your webpage.